# Gradle project version outside build.gradle at runtime

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I would like to obtain a Gradle project version in my Java code.

In Maven, it can be done this way:

version.properties:

```
version=${project.version}
```

which resolves to:

```
version=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

in jar/war if we add this to pom.xml:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Is there any convenient way to achieve similar result in Gradle? Or should I manually write a task that produces a property file with the project version and then read it in my code?

Comment: You can put the property under a file `gradle.properties` at the root project level and then refer to it in `build.gradle` file as `${myProperty}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

src/main/resources/version.properties:

```
 version=${projectVersion}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"

processResources {
    expand projectVersion: project.version
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 
For anybody who encounter the same problem - if you want several properties to be expanded you should use:

`expand([projectVersion: project.version, projectGroupId: project.groupId])`

I'm not very familiar with groovy and it was something new to me. `expand()` consumes a map as a parameter. [key1: value1, key2: value2] is a map

Comment: You can write `expand one: 1, two: 2` or `expand one: 1; expand two: 2`.

Comment: The second one was natural for me, but it doesn't work, so I had to find another way. It gives exception:
`Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: projectGroupId for class: SimpleTemplateScript7`

First one is ok.

Comment: need to build the project with Gradle for this to take effect.....I ran tests from the IDE ... but it returned `${projectVersion}` ...this may be sort of obvious to some...but i was stumped by this for some time.

Comment: Also if you want to filter properties files use: `processResources { filesMatching('version.properties') { expand projectVersion: project.version } }`